# Why was my question about a yahoo community table outage downvoted?

Tags: support

I asked a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940827/does-anyone-know-when-the-yahoo-finance-quotes-server-cluster-will-be-fixed)) about restoration of the yahoo.finance.quotes community table, which has been working intermittently since last Friday (8/25/2017), and the question has been downvoted twice without any comment or explanation. What gives?

In my opinion, I can't explain the issue any better; queries that have returned results for years are now failing intermittently. It appears to be a problem with the query.yahooapis.com server or load balancer. What more can I say? All that I'm looking for is a way to alert the system administrator to the problem, and yahoo's developer documentation suggests posting support questions here on stackoverflow.

Comment: *yahoo's developer documentation suggests posting support questions here on stackoverflow* - Their documentation is wrong. Programming questions using their API are on topic here but customer support queries are not.

Comment: You'd have to ask the voters about that. Unfortunately, those voters are anonymous, so we can't. What's left is *only going to amount to speculation*.

Answer (score 21):

We're not the system administrators for that service.  Contacting them by Stack Overflow (or at least attempting to) to alert them of outages is *not* the correct course of action here, regardless of what they tell you.

Questions regarding the API or anything specific to programming would be on-topic.  Outages and service degradation is something you need to send them an email for.